# Issue with loop printing in perl in file parsing

Tags: regex, perl, sequence, text-parsing

I have this result from phobius which looks like the following

```
ID   sp|Q92673|1-2157
FT   SIGNAL        1     28       
FT   DOMAIN        1     11       N-REGION.
FT   DOMAIN       12     22       H-REGION.
FT   DOMAIN       23     28       C-REGION.
FT   DOMAIN       29   2135       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
FT   TRANSMEM   2136   2156       
FT   DOMAIN     2157   2157       CYTOPLASMIC.
//
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   sp|Q5SSG8|25-479
FT   DOMAIN        1    455       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
//
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   sp|Q92854|22-734
FT   DOMAIN        1    713       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
//
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   sp|Q9Y5E9|27-686
FT   DOMAIN        1    660       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
// 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   sp|Q9Y6N8|55-613
FT   DOMAIN        1    559       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
//
```

I wish to print the correspoing Uniprot ID in front of each line for each result seperated by `\\`.

Here is the perl snippet I created

```
open (MYFILE, "result_phobius.txt" )||warn "Couldn't open file because $!"; #give input file name
open (FILE, ">output.txt"); #output file name
while (<MYFILE>)
{
    if ($_=~/^ID   (\S+?)\s/) #search accession number started by > and terminate at white space
    {
        $id=$1;
        chomp ($id);
        print FILE "$id\t"; #will print accession number in a column
    }
        if ($_=~/^FT   /)
        
    {
        print FILE "$_";
        
    }
}
```

This prints the ID only in first line i.e, It works perfectly fine with the results having single domain but fails if there are more than one domain.

for example

```
FT   SIGNAL        1     28       
FT   DOMAIN        1     11       N-REGION.
FT   DOMAIN       12     22       H-REGION.
FT   DOMAIN       23     28       C-REGION.
FT   DOMAIN       29   2135       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
FT   TRANSMEM   2136   2156       
FT   DOMAIN     2157   2157       CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q5SSG8|25-479    FT   DOMAIN        1    455       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q92854|22-734    FT   DOMAIN        1    713       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q9Y5E9|27-686    FT   DOMAIN        1    660       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q9Y6N8|55-613    FT   DOMAIN        1    559       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q02763|23-748    FT   DOMAIN        1    726       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q14517|22-4181   FT   DOMAIN        1   4160       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|O75051|35-1237   FT   DOMAIN        1   1203       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
tr|D3DPA4|1-145 FT   DOMAIN        1    119       CYTOPLASMIC.
FT   TRANSMEM    120    144       
FT   DOMAIN      145    145       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
```

how may I make it work for multiple entries.

expected output

```
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   SIGNAL        1     28       
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   DOMAIN        1     11       N-REGION.
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   DOMAIN       12     22       H-REGION.
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   DOMAIN       23     28       C-REGION.
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   DOMAIN       29   2135       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   TRANSMEM   2136   2156       
sp|Q92673|1-2157    FT   DOMAIN     2157   2157       CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q5SSG8|25-479    FT   DOMAIN        1    455       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q92854|22-734    FT   DOMAIN        1    713       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q9Y5E9|27-686    FT   DOMAIN        1    660       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q9Y6N8|55-613    FT   DOMAIN        1    559       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q02763|23-748    FT   DOMAIN        1    726       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|Q14517|22-4181   FT   DOMAIN        1   4160       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
sp|O75051|35-1237   FT   DOMAIN        1   1203       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
tr|D3DPA4|1-145     FT   DOMAIN        1    119       CYTOPLASMIC.
tr|D3DPA4|1-145     FT   TRANSMEM    120    144       
tr|D3DPA4|1-145     FT   DOMAIN      145    145       NON CYTOPLASMIC.
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: This looks like a program that would be easier to maintain and more flexible if you wrote it as a Unix filter. Remove all the file opening. Read from `STDIN`, write to `STDOUT` and call it like `my_program.pl < result_phobius.txt > output.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `print FILE "$id\t"` into the other `if` block, i.e. only populate the $id when it's specified, print it for every domain.

You might add a check that the $id isn't empty before printing it, but it shouldn't happen if I understand the format correctly.

```perl
   if (/^ID   (\S+?)\s/)
   {
        $id = $1;
   }
   if (/^FT   /)
   {
        print FILE "$id\t$_";
   }
```

Comment: ..I tries this ``` if ($_=~/^FT   /) print FILE "$id\t"; {
  print FILE "$_";
  
 }
} ```     but it prints the uniprot names twice, once with ID line and second time with all FT lines

Comment: @Kay: I said "into the block", not "before". Updated the answer.

Comment: ... Thanks                ```{
 if ($_=~/^ID   (\S+?)\s/) #search accession number started by > and terminate at white space
 {
  $id=$1;
  chomp ($id);
  #print FILE "$id\t"; #will print accession number in a colomn
 }
  if ($_=~/^FT   /)
  
 {
  print FILE "$id\t";
  print FILE "$_";
  
 }
} ```           this helps as well